# Get post title by Alphabet

Tags: posts, functions, errors, title, select

I try to call this function to get a list of posts by alphabet. But for some reason i keep getting an error. Call to a member function get_col() on a non-object.

What am i doing wrong?

```
{function get_post_by_alphabet($the_char){
$first_char = $the_char;

$postids=$wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
SELECT      ID
FROM        $wpdb->posts
WHERE       SUBSTR($wpdb->posts.post_title,1,1) = %s
ORDER BY    $wpdb->posts.post_title",$first_char)); 

if ($postids) {
$args=array(
  'post__in' => $postids,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
 echo 'List of Posts Titles beginning with the letter '. $first_char;
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    echo '<li><a href="'.the_permalink().'" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to '.the_title_attribute().'"><'.the_title().'</a></li>';
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
}
}

get_post_by_alphabet('H');
}
```

Comment: I think you need to `global $wpdb;` before you can use it.

Comment: That fixed the error :) But now this is the output i get: http://phplord.nl/roche/phb/werving-selectie-en-onboarding/ziekteverzuim/betermelding/BetermeldingBetermelding

but it needs to be a link inside a listitem... Any idea whats going wrong?

Comment: The link 404s, but I posted an answer with my suspicions.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. First need to `global $wpdb;`.  Then you are using `the_title()` and `the_permalink()` both of which automatically echo out a value. So you need to switch them to [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) and [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink).

```
function get_post_by_alphabet($the_char){

global $wpdb;

$first_char = $the_char;

$postids=$wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
SELECT      ID
FROM        $wpdb->posts
WHERE       SUBSTR($wpdb->posts.post_title,1,1) = %s
ORDER BY    $wpdb->posts.post_title",$first_char)); 

if ($postids) {
$args=array(
  'post__in' => $postids,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
 echo 'List of Posts Titles beginning with the letter '. $first_char;
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to '.the_title_attribute().'"><'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
}
}

get_post_by_alphabet('H');
```

Comment: Why call 2 DB queries? You have 2 possibilities to run only one: *(1)* Use only the custom query, retrieving all table cols and adding to `WHERE` clause a condition for post status. This solution will need a foreach loop with `setup_postdata` to show results *(2)* Use only the `WP_Query` with a filter on `'posts_where'` to add the `SUBSTR` statement on `WHERE` clause. This second solution is probably better.

Comment: I'd agree that reducing queries is the way to go! But, I really only looked at solving the OP's initial "non-object" issue and then the incorrect echoing of `the_title()`, etc. Seems like every time I look at it the question gets more complex.